# Close all ANOVA windows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to close all the figure windows in MATLAB.

I've used

```
close all
```

but it leaves open all the ANOVA tables!

Any way to close all those too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`close all hidden` should do the job.